# How to integrate javascript code in wordpress admin panel latest version

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, browser, chat

I want to put tawk.to chat in my admin panel here is js code which I am putting this by `add_action('admin_head')` hook

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var Tawk_API=Tawk_API||{}, Tawk_LoadStart=new Date();
    (function(){
        var s1 = document.createElement("script"), 
            s0 = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
            s1.async=true;
            s1.src='https://embed.tawk.to/5a57310ed7591465c706a3b3/default';
            s1.charset='UTF-8';
            s1.setAttribute('crossorigin','*');
            s0.parentNode.insertBefore(s1,s0);
    })();
</script>
```

But the problem is that it's not working on wordpress latest version 4.9.2 in my localhost. I installed 4.8.5 and it's working great as I want. I don't know what should I do.

And one more thing in latest version its work in safari but not in chrome and firefox, please help me.

Comment: `But the problem is that it's not working`. what you mean with this? any errors?

Comment: Its not working not showing on 4.9.2 version but previous version chat box appear

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Works on all the versions including latest.

```
function my_enqueue() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my_custom_script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/myscript.js' );
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue' );
```

You will find the details [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_enqueue_scripts).

#### Edit:

Try `get_theme_file_uri('/myscript.js');` instead of `get_template_directory_uri() . '/myscript.js'` if it doesn't work for you. Sometimes causes problem with child themes.

Comment: It did for me several days ago with the latest version. I just used it in 4.9.2

Comment: This was the code: 

function nav_menu_admin_scripts(){
        wp_enqueue_media();
        wp_enqueue_script('nav_menu_script', 
        get_theme_file_uri('/custom_menu/nav_menu_custom_script.js'), array('jquery'), '', true);
    }
    
    add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'nav_menu_admin_scripts');

Comment: Dear Aqib i am applying this to Admin panel not in frontend please ready my question carefully.

Comment: The code I gave you add a js file in admin panel. not in front end. :)

Comment: please test my script in your environment on latest version of wordpress